# malloc and pointers in assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to implement a linked list in assembly, so I have an 'array' (actually 20 bytes) to save the link for 5 possible lists.
each 'link' is 5 bytes long (1 for data 4 for pointer - x86 machine).
Now I called malloc and created 1 link and pushed a number into the first byte (decimal number) and moved the link pointer to the start of the array.
after that I try to call malloc again to create a new link but the new link created overwrites the link I have allready pushed into the array and I have no idea why!!!.
here is the code and some input/output examples:

```
section .rodata
LC0:
    DB  "The number is: %i", 10, 0  ;  string

LC1:
    DB  "Memory allocation failed!!!", 10, 0    ;  string


section .data
section .bss

numbers_stack:
    RESB    20

link:
    RESB    link_size   

section .text
align 16
global main
extern printf
extern malloc
extern gets
link_size EQU 5

_start:
jmp main 

main:

%macro  mymalloc 2  ;malloc macro
mov edx, %1 ; size to allocate
push edx
call malloc
add esp,4
test eax,eax
jz fail_exit
mov [%2], eax
%endmacro

%macro myprintf 1 ;printing macro
push %1
push LC0
call printf
add esp,8
%endmacro

mymalloc link_size,link
mov byte[link], 44
mov dword[numbers_stack],link

mov eax,0
mymalloc link_size,link ; allocate new link - *at this point the contents are allready overwritten

mov eax,[numbers_stack] ; get pointer to list head from numbers_array[0] into eax
mov edx,0
mov dl,byte[eax]
myprintf edx
```

output examples:
it will always print out the number '40' where its supposed to print out '44'
if i delete the second mymalloc it will print 44 as expected, please help! why is it still pointed to the old memory location when I obviously allocated a new one?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically missing one level of indirection. `malloc` will return a pointer that you store in `link` (thus it's size should be 4, not `link_size`). Then, when you do `mov byte[link], 44` you are overwriting this pointer and not writing into the allocated memory region. You need to load the pointer into a register (but of course malloc already returned it in `eax`) and then dereference that, such as:

```
mov eax, [link]
mov byte [eax], 44
```

You will also need to adjust the pointer there and you don't need the `numbers_stack` at all, lists just have a `head` pointer. You might want to use the common established names such as `head`, `next` and `node` so that others can more easily understand what you are talking about.

PS: if you are using libc functions you should use entry point `main` and not `_start` and link with all the necessary startup objects so that `libc` has a chance to initialize properly. You should finally just `ret` from `main`, or use the `exit` function but not the `exit` syscall.

---

**Update**: here is a possible implementation that allocates 2 lists and prints the first value from each:

```
section .rodata
LC0:
    DB  "The number is: %i", 10, 0  ;  string
LC1:
    DB  "Memory allocation failed!!!", 10, 0    ;  string

section .bss

struc node
    .next resd 1
    .value resb 1
endstruc

list_heads:
    RESD    5

section .text
global main
extern printf
extern malloc
extern gets

main:

%macro  mymalloc 1  ;malloc macro
push %1 ; size to allocate
call malloc
add esp,4
test eax,eax
jz fail_exit
%endmacro

%macro myprintf 1 ;printing macro
push %1
push LC0
call printf
add esp,8
%endmacro

mymalloc node_size
mov [list_heads], eax
mov dword [eax + node.next], 0
mov byte [eax + node.value], 44

mymalloc node_size
mov [list_heads + 4], eax
mov dword [eax + node.next], 0
mov byte [eax + node.value], 11

mov eax, [list_heads] ; get pointer to first list head
movzx edx, byte [eax + node.value]
myprintf edx

mov eax, [list_heads + 4] ; get pointer to second list head
movzx edx, byte [eax + node.value]
myprintf edx
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to save 5 possible head pointers, how can I manage all 5 lists without a structure to hold the pointers to the list heads? , and why wouldent i want to allocate  link in the size of 5? i need 1 byte of data + 4 for "next" pointer

Comment: Oh okay, if you want 5 lists then yeah, you need that.

Comment: It still dosent work...im either missing something or I didnt understand you, I have changed the code to be:

`mymalloc link_size,link
mov eax,[link]
mov byte [eax],44
mov [link], eax      

mov dword[numbers_stack],link ; move list head to numbers_array[0]


mymalloc link_size,link ; allocate new link
mov eax,[link]
mov byte [eax],16
mov [link], eax`
              
but it still wont work, I also changed `link_size` to be 4